# required keyword not working with angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

`require` keyword is not working with angular, throwing an error:

`` src/app/app.component.ts(8,16): error TS2591: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig. ``

How can I resolve it? Actually I have installed it with nodejs properly also, but not working.

Comment: Check my answer it would help you

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Restart your angular cli server and close the vs code and open again

Comment: Done it, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use require in your code follow these step

First instal this pacakge

```
npm i -D @types/node
```

Then in your tsconfig.json

```
"typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types", //add this
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

1. As others said, do you *need* `require`? Go with ES6 imports.
2. If, however, you do need `require`, you can precede it with `declare const require: any`. Worked for me.

Comment: Why do you need to use `declare const require: any` ? Because typescript already include `types/node`

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. TS configuration _should_ work, but apparently I'm missing something. `declare` line looks hacky, I concede the point,  but solves the problem for me.

Comment: Nope. Imagine you have a lot of file and need to use require. That is not happy case

Comment: I'm not arguing that. But I have a single `require` statement in the entire project. As I said, it works for _me_.

Comment: Yes I know :D Just saying we should do something that make our life easy